# Edit title and header in GridView DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I put in my GridView in devExpress a title and header:

```
settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
   settings.Settings.ShowTitlePanel = true;
```

Can you show me how to add a title and to edit header, because it displays 
***Drag a column header here to group by that column***.

And this is my GridView code:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
       {
           settings.Name = "GridView";
           settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";
           settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
           settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow = true;
           settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
           settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectSingleRowOnly = true;
           settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
           settings.Settings.ShowTitlePanel = true;
           settings.Settings.ShowFooter = true;
           settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick = "function(s, e){rowSelected(s, e)}";

           settings.Columns.Add("CodeArticle");
           settings.Columns.Add("Prix").Width = Unit.Pixel(200); ;
           settings.Columns.Add("Designation");
           settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;

       }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.SettingsText.Title = "Liste Des Articles";
           settings.SettingsText.GroupPanel = "Liste Des Articles";

Answer (score 0):

You have different main members which affect the element's appearance and functionality:

```
//Visibility:
myDevExpressGrid.Settings.ShowTitlePanel="true";
//Contents:
myDevExpressGrid.SettingsText.Title = "My Title";
//Style:
myDevExpressGrid.Styles.TitlePanel.Border.....;
myDevExpressGrid.Styles.TitlePanel.BackColor....;
myDevExpressGrid.Styles.TitlePanel.....
//You have a lot of different choices to custom your Title
//Template:
myDevExpressGrid.Templates.Titlepanel...;
//Same that Styles, you have a lot of different choices to custom it
```